# clustering customers in R with transactional data

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

How can we cluster customers from transaction data in R ? For e.g., we have customer name,product code,product family,product modules and units they bought .....now i want to find some pattern via clustering. I have looked over k-means and som in R but not getting the right approach to do it. kindly help

PS: My data is not numeric data,they are categorical

Comment: Welcome to SO. At the moment this question is too broad to be sensibly answered.  Is your problem with choosing a type of cluster analysis? Or with writing R code?  You need to make your question more specific, and describe what you have done already, or it will be closed.

Comment: Both the problems exist for me. According to k-means or SOM both should work for this particular problem but I not very sure if I am following correct approach of cluster analysis. Also when I am trying this in R with k-means clusters are getting created but its getting hard to plot and identify patterns within the data because as soon as I am plotting it, it shows me a black screen. And with SOM I am not understanding the syntax of the clustering via SOM with both SOM or kohonen package as I am not getting what are xdim and y dim values or what should be grid ? How to assume these values ?

Comment: That's a lot of different questions on rather different topics.  Start by trying to figure out what questions you want to answer about your data, and then you can decided on a statistical method. The folks at CrossValidated will help you. http://stats.stackexchange.com/  Programming problems come later.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out [rattle](http://rattle.togaware.com/). It's a friendly GUI for R that has an association rules function. To access rattle from the command line, type:

```
install.packages("rattle")

library(rattle)
rattle()
```